# MongoDb application security

Tags: mongodb

I'm checking with MongoDB application. There is application installed on my system, when I enter single quote(') in the input box it pop up the following error:

```
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.
 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mongo/2.2.3/dbparse.py in ()
     41 print "</th>"
     42 if where:
=>   43    for record in collection.find(where):
     44         print "<tr>"
     45         print "<td align=\"center\">"+record["test"]+"</td>"
record undefined, collection = Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'test_d'), u'london_garages'), collection.find = <bound method Collection.find of Collection(Data...', 27017), u'test_d'), u'l_g')>, where = {'$where': "this.test== ''--'"}
```

What is the meaning of the error? If you have another pointer to check the security of this application please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the error and the following part:

```
 where = {'$where': "this.test== ''--'"}
```

I assume the single quote goes to the where clause (some sort of search), so your code is probably something like the following:

```
where = {'$where': "this.test== '[YOUR TEXT BOX INPUT]--'"}
```

A single quote terminated your where clause prematurely. This is a good demonstration for a NoSQL injection.